# strapi error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')

Tags: javascript, strapi

Im using strapi api for my backend and I went and created a new collection called placed-orders which I will use for posting orders. In my controller file, I modified it but I keep getting the error mentioned above. This is the `placed-order.js` file in my controller folder. I can't seem to find a working solution online. Any insights will be appreciated.

```js
    "use strict";
    
    /**
     * placed-order controller
     */
    
    const { createCoreController } = require('@strapi/strapi').factories;
    
    module.exports = createCoreController('api::placed-order.placed-order', ({strapi})=>({
        async create(ctx) {
            try {
              const data = ctx.request.body;
              const submission = await strapi.services.order.create(data);
              return { success: true, submission };
            } catch (err) {
              ctx.throw(500, err);
            }
        },
    
    }));
```